# mono wsdl tool fails to parse salesforce enterprise.wsdl

Tags: mono, wsdl, salesforce

Anyone know why this wsdl is not liked by the mono wsdl tool? Microsoft parses it. XMethods online wsdl validator parses it. Mono just doesn't seem to like it and I do not know enough to understand why.

```
# the error
mmcaughan@mmcaughan-dsktop:~/Projects/sftest$ wsdl enterprise.wsdl
Web Services Description Language Utility
Mono Framework v2.0.50727.1433
```

There where some warnings while generating the code:

> enterprise.wsdl
>       - This web reference does not conform to WS-I Basic Profile v1.1
>           R2718: A wsdl:binding in a DESCRIPTION MUST have the same set of
>           wsdl:operations as the wsdl:portType to which it refers.
>             * Binding 'SoapBinding', in Service Description
>               'urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com'
>
> Writing file 'SforceService.cs'

## relevant WSDL parts (I think)

```
  <!-- Soap PortType -->
    <portType name="Soap">
        <operation name="login">
            <documentation>Login to the Salesforce.com SOAP Api</documentation>
            <input message="tns:loginRequest"/>
            <output message="tns:loginResponse"/>
            <fault message="tns:LoginFault" name="LoginFault"/>
            <fault message="tns:UnexpectedErrorFault" name="UnexpectedErrorFault"/>
            <fault message="tns:InvalidIdFault" name="InvalidIdFault"/>
        </operation>


 <!-- Soap Binding -->
    <binding name="SoapBinding" type="tns:Soap">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="login">
            <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <input>
                <soap:header use="literal" message="tns:Header" part="LoginScopeHeader"/>
                <soap:body parts="parameters" use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
            <fault name="LoginFault">
                <soap:fault name="LoginFault" use="literal"/>
            </fault>
            <fault name="UnexpectedErrorFault">
                <soap:fault name="UnexpectedErrorFault" use="literal"/>
            </fault>
            <fault name="InvalidIdFault">
                <soap:fault name="InvalidIdFault" use="literal"/>
            </fault>
        </operation>
```

Comment: Here's the port section
<!-- Soap PortType -->
<portType name="Soap">
<operation name="login">
<documentation>Login to the Salesforce.com SOAP Api</documentation>
<input message="tns:loginRequest"/>
<output message="tns:loginResponse"/>
<fault message="tns:LoginFault" name="LoginFault"/>
<fault message="tns:UnexpectedErrorFault" name="UnexpectedErrorFault"/>
<fault message="tns:InvalidIdFault" name="InvalidIdFault"/>
</operation>

Comment: Binding section...
<binding name="SoapBinding" type="tns:Soap">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<operation name="login">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:header use="literal" message="tns:Header" part="LoginScopeHeader"/>
<soap:body parts="parameters" use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
<fault name="LoginFault">
<soap:fault name="LoginFault" use="literal"/>
</fault>
</operation>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Older and more wiser now...

generate the C# from the wsdl
wsdl enterprise.wsdl -n:Sforce -o:SforceService.cs

the XmlAnyElement cannot have an empty namspace, so pop open SforceService.cs and remove it

this...
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElement(Namespace="")]
public System.Xml.XmlElement[] Any {
    get {
        return this.anyField;
    }
    set {
        this.anyField = value;
    }
}

becomes...
public System.Xml.XmlElement[] Any {
    get {
        return this.anyField;
    }
    set {
        this.anyField = value;
    }
}

wsdl generates xml serialization against private members which doesn't work and has to be fixed

Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Member LoginScopeHeaderValueField not found in class Sforce.SforceService.

this...
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderAttribute("LoginScopeHeaderValueField")]

becomes...
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderAttribute("LoginScopeHeaderValue")]

search and replace ValueField" for ValueField"

then you might get this, which is a failure because mono does not install any root certificates in the trust store so https fails

Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: Error writing request: The authentication or decryption has failed.
  at System.Net.WebConnectionStream.WriteHeaders () [0x00000] 
  at System.Net.WebConnectionStream.SetHeaders (System.Byte[] buffer) [0x00000] 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Net.WebConnectionStream:SetHeaders (byte[])
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SendRequestHeaders (Boolean propagate_error) [0x00000]

it is fixed with mozroots which will get all the certs mozilla ships with...

mozroots --import --sync

then everything works as describe

Sforce.SforceService binding = new Sforce.SforceService();
Sforce.LoginResult loginResult = binding.login("someuser", "somepass"); 
etc...